# mac address of machine from non ie browsers

Tags: firefox, scripting, mac-address

I really wanna get the mac Address of windows machine from non IE browsers. (I know this is violating the privacy of the user but my client needs it and we cant help it but comply).

I have achieved it in IE using activex object.

For non IE browsers as per google signed Applet is the only feasible way but loading of applet is taking more time than acceptable.

How can I do it properly?

PS: I'm mainly looking to achieve this in FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a java applet to do this:

http://techdetails.agwego.com/2008/02/11/37/

Answer (score 0):

Why does your client require you to obtain what is essentially private and meaningless over the internet (I assume that this is not LAN/intranet application) and easily fake-able information. What is the point of this exercise?

Comment: Well, requests are routed through NetScalar load balancer (LB) and LB is showing the virtual IP of it when it forwards the request to server. Some internal fraud they wanna figure out and pin point, so their first choice was to alter the application.

Comment: Its resolved now. We checked with the LB team and with minor modification, its now sending the IP of the client PC's.